# Confluence 5 User Macro parameters limitations?

Tags: macros, confluence

I'm writing a User Macro in Confluence 5 and I found that the 10th parameter is not being interpreted.

This is my macro header:

```
## @param ArtifactVersion:title=Artifact Version|type=string|required=true
## @param Contacts:title=Contacts|type=string|required=true
## @param Date:title=Date|type=date|required=true
## @param RollbackVersion:title=Rollback Version|type=string|required=true
## @param QaEngineer:title=QA Engineer|type=string|required=false
## @param ArtifactId:title=Artifact Id|type=string|required=true
## @param SiteName:title=Site Name|type=string|required=true
## @param Servers:title=Servers|type=string|required=true
## @param Instance:title=Instance|type=enum|enumValues=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10|required=true
## @param MyParam:title=My Param|type=string|required=true
```

If I add another param (MyParam) then it is not being interpreted. It just prints $paramMyParam literally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that there is an underlying limitation of 9 params in Confluence user macros. Whether or not this is a deliberate design decision, a limitation of the underlying architecture, or simply an oversight/bug, I cannot say.

If this is a deal-breaker for your macro, you could consider re-writing it as a fully-fledged [Macro module](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Macro+Module) using a Java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain you can have the 10th parameter, but I believe you could combine 2 parameters into 1 to allow room for the last one.

Artifact version and Artifact ID sound like they could be parsed out of the same string, similar to the way you would do so for the list of servers you have for your 8th parameter.